# Не срабатывает страница 404.php WordPress

Tags: wordpress, error404

Создала файл 404.php, но срабатывает весьма странно. Если в адресе указывать цифры, то перебрасывает на 404.php, если же ввести латиницей что-то, то перебрасывает не на 404.php, а на index.php. подскажите, пожалуйста, от чего это зависит и как это можно исправить?

Так же пробовала в .htaccess дописать строчку ErrorDocument 404 ~/404.php , но это тоже не дало нужного эффекта

Comment: Неправильный редирект во всех случаях. См в плагинах или даже теме.

Comment: @SeVlad это может быть из-за плагина перевода ссылок на латиницу?в остальном все как обычно просто делаю

Comment: Маловероятно. Такие плагины не делают редиректов. Разве что это как-то совсем левый плагин.

Comment: Вы можете это легко проверить отключив плагины/переключить на дефолтную тему, если проблема в теме.